# Force iframes on other sites clear cache when loading your content

Tags: javascript, html, caching, iframe, leaflet

I have an interactive map using Leaflet and D3.  Other sides are embedding this map in an iframe.  Mapquest just changed their map tile offering, so we had to switch to a different provider.

Problem is that anyone who has already viewed the map will not get the new JS file even on a page refresh.  I've added meta tags to the HTML file to prevent caching, but again anyone who's already viewed the app isn't going to get the updated HTML.

Any suggestions on how to get these iframes to load the updated content?

Comment: Do these sites embed iframe themselves or do they insert a script of yours that generates iframe?

Comment: They embed the iframe themselves.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?